# How to CloudDeploy an APIFunction that takes audio as input?

Tags: sound, wolfram-cloud, web-access, cloud-deploy, api

I have a function whose argument is `Audio` and I'd like to deploy it as an API (and then call it from Python). This works as with `FormPage[]` as follows:

```
CloudDeploy[
 FormPage[{{"ex", "Upload WAV file:"} -> "UploadedFile"}, 
  AudioPlot@Import[#ex] &]]
```

But I'm not sure how to set it up with `APIFunction[]` and then call it as a HTTP GET request. I can assume they are WAV files if that makes it easier.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can create an `APIFunction` with a very similar syntax and return e.g. a png"

```
CloudDeploy[
  APIFunction[
    {{"ex", "Upload WAV file:"} -> Restricted["UploadedFile", "WAV"]}
  , HTTPResponse[ExportString[AudioPlot@Import[#ex, "WAV"], "PNG"]] &
  ]
, "api/audioPlot"
, Permissions -> "Public"
];
```

Can't say how to call it from Python but from WL it goes like this:

```
req = HTTPRequest[
  CloudObject["api/audioPlot"]
, <|"Body" -> {"ex" -> File[path/to/file.wav]}|>
];

URLExecute[req, "PNG"]
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, this answer doesn't seem to work in V12, the `URLExecute` now returns a `Failure` object with the message *"Import::fmterr: Cannot import data as PNG format."*

Comment: Has something changed in APIFunction or URLExecute?